# I'm stuck trying to list in a template all the attributes of a parent attribute called a marca

Tags: wordpress

good morning, I'm stuck trying to list in a WordPress template all the attributes of a parent attribute called marca. For you to understand me it is a pharmacy and it has an attribute called marca (pa_marca) and from it hang more than 300 different marcas and I want to show them in a separate page with links.
similar to https://www.dosfarma.com/content/13-marcas

thank you I'm very lost I'm just coded this and I do not know where to continue

```
<? php

$ args = array (
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_query' => array (
array (
'key' => 'pa_marca',
'value' => 'yes',
'compare' => '=',
'posts_per_page' => -1
)
)
);
$marcas = new WP_Query ($ args); ?>
```